# Iterate server list with dbatools?

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I am really new to PowerShell and still learning so I am having a requirement to run some of the commands from dbatools and save the results.

```
$servers = 'E:\DBA\servers.txt'
$outfile = 'E:\DBA\out.csv'

Get-Content $servers | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Command DbaBackupHistory -SQLServer $_ | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $outFile}
```

I am unsure if this is the correct way to doit 
https://dbatools.io/functions/get-dbabackuphistory/

Comment: Why was this question moved off of the DBA site. It is PowerShell and related to the dbatools module....which both deal with SQL Server, so it would fall under a DBA question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified you script and tested. Worked for me.  I added 2 more switches to limit result set. `-database` and `-lastfull`. You can check documentation for details.

```
$outfile = 'c:\out.csv'

Get-Content c:\servers.txt|foreach-object {get-DbaBackupHistory -SqlServer $_  
-database dbadatabase -lastfull | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $outFile}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could solve it a bit after that but no less I appreciate the help

Comment: `Get-DbaBackupHistory` supports piping so you could just as easily do `Get-Content 'C:\servers.text | Get-DbaBackupHistory -Database DbaDatabase -LastFull | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ExportTo-Csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Path $outfile`